# Load HighCharts though .NET Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, highcharts

I am trying to load the jQuery Highcharts charts through a .Net Ajax call but not having much luck.

I can populate the chart as follows and have no problem with it displaying:

```
function LoadTopActionsChartComplete() {
            var chart1;
            $g(function () {
                chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                 chart: {
                           renderTo: 'divTopActionChart',
                           type: 'bar',
                           backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
                  },
                  title: {
                           text: 'Top Performing Actions'
                  },
                   credits: {
                             enabled: false
                   },
                  xAxis: {
                           categories:["1","2","3","4","5"]
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                            title: {
                            text: ''
                            }
                 },
                  series:[
                            {name: 'Link1',data:[703]},
                            {name: 'Link2',data:[661]},
                            {name: 'Link3',data:[649]},
                            {name: 'Link4',data:[615]},
                            {name: 'Link5',data:[611]}
                         ]
              });

            });

        }



</script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = LoadTopActionsChartComplete();
</script>
```

In order to load this on an Ajax call I implemented the following:

```
 $g(function PageLoad() {     
        LoadTopActionsChart();
    });

function LoadTopActionsChart() 
    {
        CampaignResultsNew.LoadTopActionsChart(LoadTopActionsChart_Callback);

    }

    function LoadTopActionsChart_Callback(response) {
        alert(response.value);
        LoadTopActionsChartComplete(response.value)
    }


    function LoadTopActionsChartComplete(chartScript) {
            var chart1;
            $g(function () {
                chart1 = chartScript;
            });

        }
```

The function "LoadTopActionsChartComplete" is successfully reciving the following code but this doesn't allow anything to be rendered on page.

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
                 chart: {
                           renderTo: 'divTopActionChart',
                           type: 'bar',
                           backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
                  },
                  title: {
                           text: 'Top Performing Actions'
                  },
                   credits: {
                             enabled: false
                   },
                  xAxis: {
                           categories:["1","2","3","4","5"]
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                            title: {
                            text: ''
                            }
                 },
                  series:[
                            {name: 'Link1',data:[703]},
                            {name: 'Link2',data:[661]},
                            {name: 'Link3',data:[649]},
                            {name: 'Link4',data:[615]},
                            {name: 'Link5',data:[611]}
                         ]
              });
```

If someone could possibly point out where I'm going wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't load and execute Javascript that way. I'd reconsider the design, and take a look at the jQuery [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function.

Comment: You can also have your service (`CampaignResultsNew.LoadTopActionsChart`) return a valid json string describing chart options.

Comment: Thanks. Think that sounds like my best option. Will look into it now.

Answer (score 0):

With a url that spits out your chart options, you can do this using [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$(function () {

  $.getJSON("url/of/webservice/that/returns/chartoptions", function(chartOptions){  

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);

  });

})();
```

You can use a .net JSON library like [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) for your web service.

Also you might want to read about [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).